# What is the model of my bike

Tags: mountain-bike

I have anime that I lost it owners manual .. So it's question for me is here anyway to find out the model of that ? [image]

Comment: Vote to close - no effort made by OP at all.

Comment: Looks like a better quality department store bike or entry-level bike shop bike -- not the cheapest possible design, but nothing exotic.  Knowing the specific model is not really useful, as the parts are largely interchangeable with others of it's ilk.

Comment: "Viva" is a high-end bike manufacturer in Austria, but this is not one of their bikes. I suspect the maker is "warp", but since it's a cheap bike the manufacturer is likely local to you, and you don't tell us where you are. It's not the cheapest of cheap bikes, but adding nicer handlebars and front fork to a cheap bike... it's still a cheap bike.

Answer (score 3):

Guessing from the picture, the make is "Viva" and the model is "Warp". It also looks like it's a relatively low/entry level bike, and may be relatively heavy for its size, and will be equipped with a lower quality range of components. It should be noted that there is a higher-end road/transit bike manufacturer that goes by the name Viva; this does not appear to come from the same manufacturer.

I could be completely wrong... It looks like there is a web address on the chainstay. Your best bet would be to contact the manufacturer with the serial number of the bike.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its not a BSO but a low end full sus bike. The fork looks to be Suntour XCM and the rims are from AlexRims (Both very non-BSO), and a BSO would have used a coil for the rear shock (I'm guessing this is also Suntour but the pic is too blurry).

Comment: Edited the BSO comment out - I had the same problem with the blurry image.